# How to generate a new column in data.table based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r, data.table

How to generate a new column in data.table based on multiple conditions?

If it is in data.frame environment, I can use below codes.

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),b=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
df$c<-ifelse(df$b<=30,"G1",
             ifelse(df$b>30 & df$b<=60, "G2",
                    ifelse(df$b>60 & df$b<=80, "G3",
                           ifelse(df$b>80 & df$b<=90, "G4","G5"))))
```

In data.table environment, I know I can use

```
dt<-data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),b=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
dt[,d:=...]
```

to generate a new column. But how to generate df$c in dt using dt[,d:=...]?

---

How stupid am I? I didn't try. Below one works.

```
dt<-data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),b=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
dt[,d:=ifelse(b<=30,"G1",
              ifelse(b>30 & b<=60, "G2",
                     ifelse(b>60 & b<=80, "G3",
                            ifelse(b>80 & b<=90, "G4","G5"))))]
```

Thanks

Comment: try `dt[, "c" := ...]`, feel free to self answer and accept

Comment: if you mean all those *ifelse* - did you try to remove just `dt$` and put as RHS of `:=`?

Comment: Those multiple ifelse statements should be replaced with "cut"

Comment: @PierreLafortune I do not understand what you said. Could you please show me some code? Thanks.

Comment: @jangorecki I didn't use dt$ in data.table

Answer (score 5):

For cases involving recoding based on a range of values the base function `cut` helps tremendously:

```
dt[,d:= cut(b, c(-Inf, 30, 60, 80, 90, Inf), paste0("G", 1:5))]
```

Comment: I guess you implied "numerical values" when you said "a range of values" ? Thanks for the hint on `cut`, it's highly usefull :)

Comment: Thanks. This function is very helpful.